# Struts 2 Tile and REST plugin

Tags: struts2, tiles

I'm trying to get my Struts2 project running with Tiles and REST Plugin but I just can't get it working.

I've looked at the documentation for both and I think i'm doing it right. here are my files:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app metadata-complete="true" version="2.5" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- listeners -->

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- context params -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles-tradesman.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:spring-tradesman.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- filters -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <!-- filter mappings -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <!-- RESTful plugin setup -->
    <constant name="struts.mapper.class" value="rest" />
    <constant name="struts.convention.action.suffix" value="Controller"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.action.mapAllMatches" value="true"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="rest-default"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="tp"/>

    <package name="tradesman" namespace="/beta/tradesman" extends="default">

        <result-types>
            <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult"/>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor"/>
        </interceptors>

    </package>
</struts>
```

**JobAlertsController.java**

```
package uk.co.ratedpeople.tp;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Action;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;

public class JobAlertsController extends ActionSupport {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(JobAlertsController.class.getName());

    @Action(results={
        @Result(name = SUCCESS, location = "tradesman.page.jobalerts", type = "tiles")
    })
    public String index() {
        LOGGER.info("executing index action...");
        LOGGER.info("leaving index action...");
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

When i try to run the project I get this error:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:437)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:195)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:273)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:372)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5215)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:380)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:424)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: The Result type [tiles] which is defined in the Result annotation on the class [class uk.co.ratedpeople.tp.JobAlertsController] or determined by the file extension or is the default result type for the PackageConfig of the action, could not be found as a result-type defined for the Struts/XWork package [uk.co.ratedpeople.tp#rest-default#] - [unknown location]
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.DefaultResultMapBuilder.createResultConfig(DefaultResultMapBuilder.java:427)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.DefaultResultMapBuilder.createFromAnnotations(DefaultResultMapBuilder.java:399)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.DefaultResultMapBuilder.build(DefaultResultMapBuilder.java:200)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.createActionConfig(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:864)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildConfiguration(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:650)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildActionConfigs(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:335)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.ClasspathPackageProvider.loadPackages(ClasspathPackageProvider.java:53)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:215)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
    ... 15 more
27-Jul-2011 17:07:07 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

I'm sure i'm doing something really stupid but I can't see it myself. Anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I would suggest putting your struts actions in a package simply called struts, I've had much less configuration issues when using standard conventions plugin architecture. Move your actions to a package like:

> uk.co.ratedpeople.struts

instead of

> uk.co.ratedpeople.tp;

The less out of the box configuration, the better off you typically are. 
This also eliminates the need for this:

```
<constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="tp"/>
```

Second, part of your problem is with your xml configuration:

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <!-- RESTful plugin setup -->
    <constant name="struts.mapper.class" value="rest" />
    <constant name="struts.convention.action.suffix" value="Controller"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.action.mapAllMatches" value="true"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="rest-default"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="tp"/>

    <package name="tradesman" namespace="/beta/tradesman" extends="default">

        <result-types>
            <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult"/>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor"/>
        </interceptors>
</package>
```

Try something like this instead (providing you moved your actions as previously suggested):

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <!-- RESTful plugin setup -->
    <constant name="struts.mapper.class" value="rest" />
    <constant name="struts.convention.action.suffix" value="Controller"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.action.mapAllMatches" value="true"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="tradesman"/>

    <package name="tradesman" namespace="/beta/tradesman" extends="rest-default">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult"/>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Notice the constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="tradesman" which is referring to the package below it which defines your result types and extends rest-default. This should eliminate your tiles result definition errors.

I've also run into issues using the struts filter you have in your web.xml, I would change from:

```
<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
```

to:

```
<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
```

Comment: +1 for the answer and especially for mentioning the StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter (the old ActionContextCleanUp seems to cleanup the ValueStack before the view is processed). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks man that worked a treat! The main problem we found was using a different package name rather than struts, as soon as we changed that name to struts it all worked. Is there any way of getting it to work with a non standard package name or is there just no point?

Comment: Well, a setup with the <constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="rest"/> should resolve to the stated package. I just tested it with a known, working project by setting this constant and moving my actions to the new package. I would suggest that once you know the actions are resolving in the default packages to try migrating them to another configuration using the constants setting. It may just end up being an exercise of trial and error, I find that I often learn more by this methodology than any other.